# Check for linearity using a dynamic variable by a shiny widget

Tags: r, shiny

I want to use every time a different variable to put inside the `plot()` function to check for linearity using a shiny widget but I get: `variable lengths differ (found for 'input$var')`

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title="Task Managers' Workload Analysis",
    titleWidth = 400
    
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("var","Select variable",choices = colnames(diamonds),selected = colnames(diamonds)[1])
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    plotOutput("hist")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$hist<-renderPlot({
    plot(price ~ input$var, data=diamonds)
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: on a sidenote: please consider rephrasing your question so that the title reflects the actual issue (= how to use a shiny input value in a base plot formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either:

```
plot(eval(parse(text = input$var)) ~ price, data = diamonds)
```

or

```
plot(diamonds[[input$var]] ~ price, data = diamonds)
```

Comment: could u take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76115538/add-and-remove-dynamic-number-of-dependent-variables-in-a-mlr-model-of-a-shiny-a

Answer (score 1):

`input$var` is a character string, so you can't do `price ~ input$var` (this is like `price ~ "hello"`).

A possible way is to create a new dataframe in your `renderPlot`:

```r
dat <- diamonds[, c("price", input$var)]
names(dat) <- c("price", "x")
plot(price ~ x, data = dat)
```

Comment: could u take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76115538/add-and-remove-dynamic-number-of-dependent-variables-in-a-mlr-model-of-a-shiny-a

Comment: sorry, came late: there's a nice solution already there, or were you looking for an alternative