# Add and remove dynamic number of dependent variables in a mlr model of a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the `shiny` app below in which I want every time to add another independent variable in my model of multiple linear regression using a shiny widget but I cannot make it work properly and also I do not know how many variable I will finally use. I want to be able to use them all.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

diamonds<-structure(list(`Approved Amount_UA Equivalent` = c(2219168628.96743, 
7910915006.08302, 2945430613.82441, 566728468.043035, 88329573, 
1358334742.43214, 154458822.437869, 2277782734.89826, 741826741.108259, 
847582159.129072, 1073340403.95213, 69304767.7924836, 1996421218.60972, 
2285448543.98486, 1219425905.30524, 416052930.270822, 475569814.997042, 
110213600.606809, 1877512072.92976, 878178278.897963, 394121308.069995, 
794940791.885493, 870570569.250428, 2223818025.07865, 290476596.417383, 
262411644.388115, 49919237.6842862, 607024212.811439, 3034312319.45931, 
1116549963.55694, 109407208.224749, 137384009.609597, 369189707.097464, 
52384648.6575371, 3361231217.85468, 1171720315.61533, 167729174.793072, 
165214259.038085, 112288377.271093, 42620991.164361, 172482696.513884, 
466392209.103056, 744915930.376353, 136037687.882746, 101003400, 
155411250.451016, 408189979.586085, 107200000, 194742957.590488, 
349454434.398465, 389223626.467406, 118593779.953281, 1087745585.21858, 
214083569.432016, 102227495.089862, 3944346.17544808, 717068623.467266, 
62312088.8481568, 3186850.5368895, 66931325.4734835, 15331250.3471359, 
348913.280511739, 1.56e+08, 31042195.248091), `Approved Amount_USDEquivalent` = c(2958151782.41359, 
10545249703.1087, 3926259008.22793, 755449047.901366, 117743320.809, 
1810660211.66204, 205893610.30968, 3036284385.61938, 988855045.89731, 
1129827018.11905, 1430762758.46818, 92383255.4673806, 2661229484.40675, 
3046502909.13181, 1625494731.77189, 554598556.051006, 633934563.391057, 
146914729.608877, 2502723593.21537, 1170611645.77098, 525363703.657303, 
1059656075.58336, 1160470568.81082, 2964349427.42984, 387205303.024371, 
349794721.969357, 66542343.8331535, 809163275.677648, 4044738321.83925, 
1488361101.4214, 145839808.56359, 183132884.809593, 492129879.560919, 
69828736.660497, 4480521213.40029, 1561903180.71523, 223582989.999166, 
220230607.297767, 149680406.902367, 56813781.2220932, 229919434.453008, 
621700814.734373, 992972935.191679, 181338237.9477, 134637532.2, 
207163196.851204, 544117242.788252, 142897600, 259592362.468121, 
465822761.053154, 518835094.081052, 158085508.677723, 1449964865.09637, 
285373398.052877, 136269250.954786, 5257813.45187228, 955852475.081865, 
83062014.4345929, 4248071.76567371, 89219456.8561535, 20436556.7127322, 
465101.402922149, 207948000, 41379246.2657053), `High Five Prority 1: Feed Africa` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 143413724.693453, NA, 95605.5161066851, 
49742936.0998292, NA, NA, NA, 31042195.248091), `High Five Prority 2: Light Up And Power Africa` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 143413724.693453, NA, 31868.505368895, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `High Five Prority 3: Industrialize Africa` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
160494711.235755, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 143413724.693453, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.56e+08, NA), `High Five Prority 4: Integrate Africa` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 143413724.693453, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), `High Five Prority 5: Improve Quality Of Life` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 27698877.7418283, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 143413724.693453, 
NA, 3059376.51541392, NA, NA, 348913.280511739, NA, NA), `NUMBER OF PROJECT` = c(38, 
265.805555555556, 47, 22, 6, 27, 16, 42, 20.5, 26, 11, 6, 30, 
21, 12, 23, 19, 10, 27, 18, 20.1666666666667, 24, 29.5, 46.5, 
28, 12, 8, 28, 49, 23, 14.5, 17, 6, 6, 35, 12, 23, 13, 18, 3, 
15.8333333333333, 25, 26, 16, 8, 7.5, 30, 9, 15, 4, 10, 19, 17, 
13, 12, 1.5, 1, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), `Amount in UA Million` = c(2219.16862896743, 
7910.91500608303, 2945.43061382441, 566.728468043035, 88.329573, 
1358.33474243214, 154.458822437869, 2277.78273489826, 741.82674110826, 
847.582159129072, 1073.34040395213, 69.3047677924836, 1996.42121860972, 
2285.44854398486, 1219.42590530524, 416.052930270822, 475.569814997042, 
110.213600606809, 1877.51207292976, 878.178278897963, 394.121308069995, 
794.940791885493, 870.570569250428, 2223.81802507865, 290.476596417383, 
262.411644388115, 49.9192376842862, 607.024212811439, 3034.31231945931, 
1116.54996355694, 109.407208224749, 137.384009609597, 369.189707097464, 
52.3846486575371, 3361.23121785468, 1171.72031561533, 167.729174793072, 
165.214259038085, 112.288377271093, 42.620991164361, 172.482696513884, 
466.392209103056, 744.915930376353, 136.037687882746, 101.0034, 
155.411250451016, 408.189979586085, 107.2, 194.742957590488, 
349.454434398465, 389.223626467406, 118.593779953281, 1087.74558521858, 
214.083569432016, 102.227495089862, 3.94434617544808, 717.068623467266, 
62.3120888481568, 3.1868505368895, 66.9313254734835, 15.3312503471359, 
0.348913280511739, 156, 31.042195248091)), row.names = c(NA, 
-64L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
# app page
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Task Managers' Workload Analysis",
    titleWidth = 400
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    uiOutput("var_selection")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    verbatimTextOutput("mlr_output")
  )
)

 # server side actions
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # UI for variable selection based on available columns in the data
  output$var_selection <- renderUI({
    colnames <- colnames(diamonds)[-8]
    selectInput(
      "vars", 
      "Select variables", 
      choices = colnames, 
      selected = colnames[1], 
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  })
  
  # Reactively select the data based on selected variables
  data <- reactive({
    select(diamonds, contains("NUMBER OF PROJECTS"), input$vars)
  })
  
  # run multiple linear regression model, on selecting the variables
  model <- reactive({
    formula <- as.formula(paste0("NUMBER OF PRODUCTS ~ ", paste(input$vars, collapse = "+")))
    lm(formula, data = data())
  })
  
  # print summary of regression model above
  output$mlr_output <- renderPrint({
    summary(model())
  })
  
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the modified code (please note, I have included a few packages, which must be installed before running the code):

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
data(diamonds)

# app page
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Task Managers' Workload Analysis",
    titleWidth = 400
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    uiOutput("var_selection")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    verbatimTextOutput("mlr_output")
  )
)

 # server side actions
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # UI for variable selection based on available columns in the data
  output$var_selection <- renderUI({
    colnames <- colnames(diamonds)[c(1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10)]
    selectInput(
      "vars", 
      "Select variables", 
      choices = colnames, 
      selected = colnames[1], 
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  })
  
  # Reactively select the data based on selected variables
  data <- reactive({
    select(diamonds, contains("price"), input$vars)
  })
  
  # run multiple linear regression model, on selecting the variables
  model <- reactive({
    formula <- as.formula(paste0("price ~ ", paste(input$vars, collapse = "+")))
    lm(formula, data = data())
  })
  
  # print summary of regression model above
  output$mlr_output <- renderPrint({
    summary(model())
  })
  
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I ran this code, output I see:

[image]

Let me know if this helps...

For your dataset containing:

```
str(diamonds)
tibble [64 × 9] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Approved Amount_UA Equivalent                 : num [1:64] 2.22e+09 7.91e+09 2.95e+09 5.67e+08 8.83e+07 ...
 $ Approved Amount_USDEquivalent                 : num [1:64] 2.96e+09 1.05e+10 3.93e+09 7.55e+08 1.18e+08 ...
 $ High Five Prority 1: Feed Africa              : num [1:64] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ High Five Prority 2: Light Up And Power Africa: num [1:64] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ High Five Prority 3: Industrialize Africa     : num [1:64] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ High Five Prority 4: Integrate Africa         : num [1:64] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ High Five Prority 5: Improve Quality Of Life  : num [1:64] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ NUMBER OF PROJECT                             : num [1:64] 38 266 47 22 6 ...
 $ Amount in UA Million                          : num [1:64] 2219.2 7910.9 2945.4 566.7 88.3 ...
```

you should modify the above shiny app code:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Task Managers' Workload Analysis",
    titleWidth = 400
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput(
      "vars", 
      "Select variables", 
      choices = c(
        "Approved_Amt_UA" = "Approved Amount_UA Equivalent",
        "Approved_Amt_USD" = "Approved Amount_USDEquivalent",
        "HFP1FA" = "High Five Prority 1: Feed Africa",
        "HFP2LP" = "High Five Prority 2: Light Up And Power Africa",
        "HFP3IA" = "High Five Prority 3: Industrialize Africa",
        "HFP4IA" = "High Five Prority 4: Integrate Africa",
        "HFP5IQL" = "High Five Prority 5: Improve Quality Of Life",
        "NUMBER OF PROJECT" = "Num_of_Projects",
        "Amount in UA Million" = "Amt_in_UA_Million"
      ),
      selected = "Approved_Amt_UA",
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    verbatimTextOutput("mlr_output")
  )
)
```

Comment: I like your answer . I have a problem with my actual column names so I edited based on my real column names

Comment: My suggestion, you should rename the column names before using these into App. for example, `High Five Prority 1: Feed Africa` can be renamed as `HFP1FA` for better control in App

Comment: I have modified the answer and included a workaround which should help you. Please instead of `data(diamonds)`, use `df <- read.csv()` like function, assuming if you have your data into a csv file at a fixed location.